# How to run a JPA Query in Play Framework 1.2.5

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

I'm trying to run `JPA Query` on Play Framework 1.2.5 unsuccessfully.

I tried like this:

```
Query query = JPA.em().createQuery("select * from Book");
List<Book> articles = query.getResultList();
render(articles);
```

But I get error:

```
The file /app/controllers/Application.java could not be compiled. Error raised is : Query cannot be resolved to a type
```

What I gotta do?

Answer (score 2):

You have to import the Query class.

```
import javax.persistence.Query;
```

Doesn't your IDE flag such errors? SHouldn't you be able to fix basic compilation errors before using Play and JPA? Start by learning the basics of Java.

Also, `select * from Book` is not JPQL. `select b from Book b` is.